# Computer suddenly not connecting to wi-fi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a Compaq desktop computer that I have put a D-Link Wi-Fi PCI card into. This card was installed a while ago, and has worked without problems up until today.

When I woke up this morning none of the devices in my house would connect, for I don't know what reason (I wasn't the one who found that the network was nonoperational), so I power cycled my modem and router and everything was working fine- except for the Compaq desktop. The Windows on this system would say that it's wireless status is connected, however after a few seconds the status would change to "No Internet Access" and then shortly after disconnect. This is only when the computer would connect to the router, by the way- Whenever I'd try to initiate the connection manually, it wouldn't connect. The windows network troubleshooter only told me to "contact my network administrator" and gave me no more information. I still cannot connect the system even after rebooting it and power cycling the router and modem many times. On the router's configuration site, it only says that the Compaq is connected when the computer says that I have no internet access. When the computer says that I have a fully operational connection, even though the system does seem to have an IP address assigned to it, The router's site does not say that it has assigned this IP address, nor does it say the computer is connected at all.

During the short time the computer is connected to my router, I tried to ping Google to test if I was getting a connection at all. Most attempts at this returned that the "Request Timed Out" but sometimes, rarely, I'd get a reply from the site. despite this, I cannot browse any website... Not even my router's local configuration site (dlinkrouter.local)!

I installed a new GPU into this system last night, however I used the wi-fi on the system without problems after this install, so I don't think the GPU is the reason I suddenly cannot connect to the internet.

Has anyone experienced this? What's going on here and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like an IP address conflict. Check your other computer's IP addresses when you finally get the "no internet" problem which usually signifies that you have been given an IP. If you see a duplicate, you've found the problem. The solution? Unsure. Rather than spending a ton of time looking, I would probably perform a master reset of the router (small reset button usually on the back somewhere). It's possible that the router configuration was altered or started to conflict. There are a lot of possibilities actually. I tried to comment on this post to see where you were with it, but it wouldn't let me. You've probably bought a new router by now?

Comment: Actually, It seems that the computer can connect fine now, only rarely experiencing issues with connecting in the first place. The big problem I'm getting now is that the internet on the computer is EXTREMELY slow compared to what It was before the install... And no, I'm still using the same router, But I have been planning to preform a master reset as you suggested.

Comment: How old is the router? If your saying it's slow now, id definitely try the master reset. If you are needing to perform a master reset and it solves everything only temporarily, it's  possible it's time for a new router.  There are a lot of possibilities here, just throwing out a few. Routers and modem/router combos are not too expensive and are becoming much easier to set up and maintain than the older ones. In fact, if you are willing to accept the preconfigured SSID and WiFi password, it's likely no setup will be needed.

Comment: yeah, those are two of the reasons I cannot use a modem/router combo- Not enough configuration for what I need. The router I have now I bought in December of 2013, so it's pretty recent (I think?). I've been meaning to get a new router because I need gigabit routing for my computers but I lack the funds at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need further testing, however...

It sounds like it is possible that you are getting packet loss (slow speed, ping to google working sometimes, etc...). Trying pinging your router several times (like 20) and see if all the packets come back. Maybe there is wireless interference or maybe the wifi adapter is failing or the router is misbehaving. Try to ping google or something as well, to determine if the problem is with your router/internet or with your router/wireless/nic.

There could be a couple of other reasons for your problem, but this testing is where I would start.